# Should posts with "too much content" be flagged for not getting to the point quick enough?

Tags: discussion, flags

Today I saw an answer that had a tonne of content, easily one of the longest answers I've seen on Stack Overflow (possibly the entirety of Stack Exchange).

At first I wanted to down-vote simply for it being **too long**, but I had a slight moral dilemma as it looked like a lot of effort had gone into this post.

This post was so long that I could quickly two-finger-swipe up on my mouse pad and after a second or two it'd still be scrolling on its own, and I'm on a 13" screen in portrait mode.

It had so much content that the user who posted it couldn't even fit the whole answer in the post; he had to put the rest of the answer on GitHub.

Now for those of you that say *"if it's a good answer leave it be"*, please, let's be honest here; I can say with almost certainty that 99% of Stack Overflow users don't come on Stack Overflow to read a **30 thousand character** answer only to realise that the *"rest of the answer"* is another **30 thousand plus characters** on a **different site**.

- Should we welcome posts that are that are that long or look down upon them?
- Should answers that long be down voted / flagged?
- What can / should we do when it comes to posts that long?
- Should there be a rule that tells users with *"posting privileges"* to not *"post something **that long**"*?

Comment: Definitely no point in flagging - what's the moderator supposed to do about it? I typically add a comment urging the author to be more brief, but otherwise leave it alone. Can't bring myself to downvoting something that has seen a *lot* of effort if it's just too long (and not grossly incorrect).

Comment: If you need to follow a link to another site to get to the point, then such an answer is *not helpful*, so deserves a downvote. There isn't much more to say on that really.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how many max characters can an SO post contain?

Comment: It may be a good indication that the question is Too Broad.

Comment: Note that *length itself* is not an indicator of usefulness. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6581949/100297) is long, but is also very well written and very complete. It is an exceedingly helpful answer.

Comment: @suraj 30,000 characters

Comment: I personally don't think that you even need 30,000 characters to get a point across even the declaration of independence isn't 30,000 characters long... and it's the **DECLARATION OF INDEPENDENCE** (http://www.ushistory.org/DECLARATION/document/)

Comment: SO certainly isn't the place to be publishing a book. Encouraging the author to post the content as a blog post or whatever instead and only leaving the core in the answer seems the most reasonable. If the answer is indeed virtually unusable in the meantime, downvoting wouldn't be incorrect (though it does hurt).

Comment: If the question requires you to write a book. As @Tunaki said it would be too broad.

Comment: @suraj Yes, but, even if just for the sake of argument, I can see how one can get carried away and add much more content than really necessary.

Comment: @Mango: but 30.000 characters gives you scope to *expand* on your point. You can get the point across in less, then drill down into the interesting and salient details. There is a place for long answers, the problem is answers that try to go beyond by using a link.

Comment: I'm going to flag this question for using "tonne" instead of "ton"; that's two characters you made me read that I didn't have to :-P.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan It's just how we spell it, here in England we use tonne which is the same as the metric ton in the U.S.

Comment: I know, I was kidding. You were complaining about "too long posts", and... never mind.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Ohhhh now I get it... OMG I feel so bad for ruining your pun, sorry mate ;)

Comment: @Mango. Your question isn't really about answer length *per se*, but about attempting to by-pass the 30,000 char limit by linking to another site. Clearly, SO has deemed anything up to 30,000 chars acceptable, and so it would be wrong to penalise anyone who stayed within that limit. Beyond that, how is anyone to judge what is *qualitatively* "too long"? An answer of 300 chars might be considered "too long" for a simple factual question than can be correctly answered by a few words. I therefore think you need to clarify your question, and provide links to some concrete examples.

Comment: I've written a complete and final answer to this question, but it's 25000 characters long and I'm afraid to post it.

Comment: @Glorfindel post it in a blog and answer with just a link to it.

Comment: I sometimes encounter a lengthy answer but when I Googled it, it is just a copy paste from a Blog. In that case I will notify the that guy who answered and asked to summarized it and point only the important details.

Comment: @Enzokie That's very generous of you. I flag for plagiarism if it's copy/pasted without attribution.

Comment: Can we have a link to that answer, please? =)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my humble opinion, there should be three critieria for posting an answer:

1. The question should be kept to the point, not expanding into numerous topics if possible.
2. If 1. has not been met, answerers should comment the post rather than post answers to it, to guide the asker in honing the question.
3. The answer should stay within the topic(s) required by the question, stay factual, and generally avoid personal opinions, in favour of analyses, documentation (where necessary) and a to-the-point answer.

Length is in and of itself not a guide to whether or not an answer was well delivered. Different areas of study each require their own ways of both asking and answering; a question about mathematics could result in just a few lines, whereas a question in history, could require lengthy answer to adequately cover a complexity of equal level.

Therefore, I agree with @Pekka 웃’s and @Martijn Pieter’s replies, that one could comment that the author should be brief, and that if the answer is lengthy, it probably is an indication of the question being too broad; but, as Pieters shows, a lengthy answer could be both to the point *and* well written.

My conclusion, therefore, has to be that the answer should have to be judged on its own merits. Setting an absolute limit to how long an answer is, would seem counter-productive to the overall goal of SO. I would, however, suggest that answers exceeding e.g. the median ⅔ (or some other fraction that might work well, based on simple statistical analyses of the corpus of answers) of all answers *in that community*, should be encouraged to include a short abstract and presentation of structure.